# Using var in nodejs to search a json file

Tags: json, node.js

So im trying to search a json file but i tried this and it didn't return a value.

```
var info = JSON.parse(body);                      // Get File From Website
var itemforjson = item.market_hash_name;          // Get The Item Name To Try To Use It In Json
depitems[i].value = parseInt(info.itemforjson);   // Has To Be A Number
```

Comment: Could you explain more detailed what exactly is your problem? You get any error?

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question which boils down to how to access a property of an object when the property name is in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parseInt(info[itemforjson])` on the last line.

Comment: Thanks i also had to change it to a parseFloat because it has a decimal.